# How to diagnose an Access Denied error from Windows ICMP.DLL

Tags: windows, delphi, ping, icmp

Within my Delphi app, I call `IcmpSendEcho()` from `icmp.dll`. The code has been working fine for years and across multiple users on multiple platforms. However, I have one user that the call returns Access Denied.

I've run Process Monitor but nothing untowards shows up there. I've checked all the obvious access rights, I've even used a DLL browser to check that their DLL contains the appropriate function export (the DLL browser has no problem accessing the DLL) !!

I built a standalone test app for this customer, code below:

```pascal
function TForm40.PingDiagnose(InetAddress: string): boolean;
var
  IPAddress: string;
  Handle: THandle;
  InAddr: IPAddr;
  DW: DWORD;
  rep: array [1 .. 1280] of byte;//try a stupid size in case that's the problem
begin
  result := false;
  Memo1.lines.add('Attempting to get handle on icmp.dll');
  Handle := IcmpCreateFile;
  if Handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    Memo1.lines.add('Failed to get handle on icmp.dll');
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    IPAddress := '';
    Memo1.lines.add(format('Attempting to resolve IP address for %s',[InetAddress]));
    IPAddress := GetIPAddress(InetAddress);
    Memo1.lines.add(format('IP address returned %s',[IPAddress]));
    if (IPAddress <> '') then  // if internet is down, IPAddress could be an empty string
    begin
      with TIdStackWindows.create do
      begin
        TranslateStringToTInAddr(IPAddress, InAddr, Id_IPv4);
        free;
      end;
      Memo1.lines.add('Attempting to call IcmpSendEcho on icmp.dll');
      DW := IcmpSendEcho(Handle, InAddr, nil, 0, nil, @rep, 1280, 1000);
      Memo1.lines.add(format('Result returned from call: %d',[DW]));
      if DW=0 then
      begin
        Memo1.lines.add(format('Error number: %d - %s',[GetLastError, SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)]));
      end;
      result := (DW <> 0);
    end;
  finally
    IcmpCloseHandle(Handle);
  end;
end;
```

So my assumption is that it's what `IcmpSendEcho()` does next that's causing the error.

I can't find anything useful via Google, so any ideas on either what might be happening or how I can "debug" this further?

Comment: You are calling this code in a `TForm`, which has its own `Handle` that your variable of the same name is shadowing. You should use a unique name for your variable. Also, you are not calling `GetLastError()` *immediately* after `IcmpSendEcho()` fails, you are calling `SysUtils.Format()` and `TMemo.Lines.Add()` first, which could potentially wipe out the error code.

Comment: Thanks. Will address those issues and retest, however the original application is a windows service which always returns DW=0 for this customer. I only wrote the TForm app to try and diagnose what was going on.

Comment: See [Non-privileged ping Under Windows](https://www.gonwan.com/2013/04/21/non-privileged-ping-under-windows/).

Comment: After changing my code as per Remy's suggestion, I now get a different error error code 11010 : Error due to lack of resources, though I also found a comment on another stackoverflow question that says 

Windows IP Helper defines IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT error to value 11010 wich is the same as Windows system error WSA_QOS_ADMISSION_FAILURE 11010 'Error due to lack of resources.' so it is likely that what actually received in questioned case was time out error and simply misinterpreted as 'lack of resources'. 

However even using a 10 second timeout value returns the same error.

Comment: So your answer is then "by using GetLastError correctly" as @Remy stated in the first comment. FWIW, though, the problem is the first `Memo.Lines.Add`. The second statement is fine `Memo1.lines.add(format('Error number: %d - %s',[GetLastError, SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)]));` because the very first thing that is evaluated in that statement is the `GetLastError` (even twice!!). ... That's why you can safely call something like `ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));`, evaluation starts from the inner-most scope.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz correct. Though the question now I suppose should be "why does ping via the api fail when ping via cmd works fine"